# C - What's wrong with mystrtok() function?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok

I'm trying to create a function that'll do the same work as `strtok()` function does in C.  Below is my code, but the problem is that every time I run this program, it shows only the first tokenized string, then the program stops and Windows shows a pop-up saying "..... has stopped working......" & then then Code::Blocks returns  -1073741819 (0XC0000005). I don't know why this is happening — can you explain?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char a[1000],b[50];
int i=0;

char *mystrtok(char a[],char b[])
{
    char c[1000];
    char *ptr = malloc(1000*sizeof(c));
    ptr = c;
    c[0] = '\0';

    if(a == NULL)
        ++i;
    else
        i=0;

    /*printf("i is = %d\n",i);
    free(ptr);*/

    //printf("len of c is%d",strlen(c));
    int j=0,flag;

    //ptr = realloc(ptr,sizeof(c));
    for(i=i;a[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        for(j=0;b[j] != '\0';j++)
        {
            if(a[i] == b[j])
            {
                c[i] = '\0';
                return ptr;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 0;
                c[i] = a[i];
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    /*if(!flag)
        c[i] = '\0';*/
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int k;
    printf("Enter a big string: ");
    gets(a);
    printf("Enter a token: ");
    gets(b);

    char *tokenized;
    tokenized = mystrtok(a,b);
    puts(tokenized);

    while(tokenized)
    {
        tokenized = mystrtok(NULL, b);
        puts(tokenized);
    }
}
```

I've spent much time on finding what's problem with my code, and I've searched through Google & Stack Overflow help, but nothing helps me exactly.

Comment: Fakruddin Gazzali  The standard function strtok does not allocate memory. Moreover your implementation has a memory leak char *ptr = malloc(1000*sizeof(c));
ptr = c;

That is the address of the allocated memory is lost because the pointer is reassigned.

Comment: should I remove it? But is remove it, how can I get back the pointer pointing to that string c?Yesterday I read that if I want to a function to return string , then I should use `malloc()` and I should assign a pointer to that string? Is this wrong?
I'm sorry that I don't have much knowledge about pointers

Comment: Formatting/indentation :(

Comment: To rewrite `strtok()` you need a `static` variable to keep status inside the function. But maybe you want a well behaved (different) implementation???

Comment: You understand that the 'standard' strtok() is broken?  It uses static state, and so is not reeentrant and thread-unsafe.

Comment: @pmg Sorry Didn't understand that ... :(

Comment: @Md.FakruddinGazzaliFahim Yes you should remove the allocation because in any case the memory is not used, its address is lost. Also it is a bad idea that the function uses the global variable i.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow okay, trying that with internal variable ... But I should store the value of i for the next run (i.e. when I'm calling ` tokenized = mystrtok(NULL, b);` . So I thought in lobal variable might help me !

Comment: Question: in the 2nd (and later) call to `strtok()` how does it know where to look for the separators (remember you pass `NULL` fir the 1st parameter)? Answer: it keeps state in `static` objects.

Comment: @Md.FakruddinGazzaliFahim You should declare a static variable inside the function. It is better to declare it of the type char *.

Comment: @Md.FakruddinGazzaliFahim Pay attention to this for statement for(i=i;a[i] != '\0';i++)

This expression i = i; within it does not make sense.

Comment: Note that you are allocating one megabyte of memory, which seems like overkill.

Comment: Also note that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used, ever!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few bugs.  Right off the top, you allocate memory for `ptr`, then lose the reference to it by overwriting it with `c`.  That's a memory leak (and also because you never `free` it).

The main problem I think is that when the second call passes `NULL`, you lost the reference to the string you're supposed to be searching from the previous call.  You have to have some memory that persists between function calls.  `static` variables are perfect for this.

And lastly, the loop in `main` has the statements in the reverse order.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *mystrtok(char *str, const char *delim) {
  int i = 0, j;
  static char *ptr = "";
  int found;

  // new str, new search
  if(str != NULL) {
    ptr = str;
  }

  // skip delims
  while(ptr[i] != '\0') {
    found = 1;
    for(j = 0; delim[j] != '\0'; j++) {
      if(ptr[i] == delim[j]) {
        found = 0;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(found) {
      break;
    }

    i++;
  }

  if(ptr[i] == '\0') {
    return NULL;
  } else {
    ptr += i;
  }

  // find next delim
  found = 0;
  while(ptr[i] != '\0') {
    for(j = 0; delim[j] != '\0'; j++) {
      if(ptr[i] == delim[j]) {
        ptr[i] = '\0';
        found = 1;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(found) {
      break;
    }

    i++;
  }

  // record start, advance ptr
  str = ptr;
  ptr += i;

  // only skip delims
  if(found) {
    ptr++;
  }

  return str;
}

int main() {
  char a[1000];
  char b[50];

  printf("Enter a big string: ");
  gets(a);

  printf("Enter a token: ");
  gets(b);

  char *tokenized = mystrtok(a, b);

  while(tokenized != NULL) {
    puts(tokenized);
    tokenized = mystrtok(NULL, b);
  }

  return 0;
}
```